# How do I get a TTimer to repeat the functions called a limited number of times?

Tags: delphi

I want to animate a token moving across the board X number of times.

In this case, X will be the number rolled on a die.

For example, if a player rolls a 3, I want to see the token "move" to the next tile, and then 400ms later to the next tile, then 400ms later to the last tile.

I have tried using a `TTimer`, which animates this well, but it does not stop the token on the right tile. Using a `for` loop results in the token ending up on the right tile, but without animation. I just want the `TTimer` to repeat itself X number of times. :)

My code is as follows (using Delphi 2010):

**For the For Loop:**

```
for i := 1 to iNum + 1 do // iNum is the number rolled
  player1.Left := player1.Left + 200; // player1 is the token`
```

**For the TTimer:**

```
procedure TfrmSnakesNLadders.tmrMoveTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  player1.Left := player1.Left + 200;
  if player1.Left >= 850 then // 850 is the Rightmost Boundary of the token
    tmrMove.Enabled := false;
end;
```

Comment: Declare a counter  to count the moves. Set the counter to number of moves, decrement at each timer tick. Stop the timer when the counter becomes zero.

Comment: Instead of checking for the Left position, use another var to count the steps, then in the Timer event.  In other words, set a var to 0 before you enable the Timer. On each event call, increase it by 1, then if that var > iNum+1, set the timer to false.  Or call Sleep in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show us how you initialise player1.right, but it looks like a boundary condition error, i.e. your 850 value should not be 850. But to roll x times, initialise a class variable and count that. A bit like this:

```
class TfrmSnakesNLadders = class( Form )
….
private
  fNum : integer
….
```

Then initialise and start your timer, something like

```
….

procedure TfrmSnakesNLadders.InitMove;
begin
  fNum := 0;
  tmrMove.Enabled := true;
end;
```

and then animate with your timer

```
procedure TfrmSnakesNLadders.tmrMoveTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  player1.Left := player1.Left + 200;

  inc( fNum);
  if fNum >= iNum  then
    tmrMove.Enabled := false;
end;
```